# Rubymotion support for ruby 2.0 keyword arguments

Tags: rubymotion

Does Rubymotion support ruby 2.0 keyword arguments? I have this method and it throws this error: `syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting tIDENTIFIER`

```
def foo(message, offset: 20)
  # Do something
end
```

I am using the following version of Ruby, but it doesnt seem to be working?

```
$ ruby -v
vruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.2]
```

Comment: Your problem is the fact you're putting a value there instead of the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

No.

RubyMotion was released before Ruby 2.0.0, but it needed keyword arguments to interoperate with Objective-C, for example to define callback/delegate methods. So it introduced keyword arguments based on one of existing keyword arguments proposals at the time:

```
def tableView(view, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
  # ...
end
```

So in RubyMotion the argument keyword name (`numberOfRowsInSection`) is separate from the argument name (`section`), and if keyword is present in a signature, then it is required.

However, Ruby 2.0.0 decided to stick to a different design:

```
def foo(message, offset: 0)
  # ...
end
```

Argument keyword name is the same as the argument name (`offset`), they always have a default value (`0` here), and they are optional (you can call `foo(message)` without `offset` here).

This is a bit unfortunate. But I'm interested to see how will RubyMotion evolve to support Ruby 2.0.0 keyword arguments in future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Using [the Ruby Motion developer center docs](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/) as a reference, here's an example that looks a lot like what you're trying to do.

```
class DrawingProxy
  def drawAtPoint(point, withFont:font)
    @str.drawAtPoint(point, withFont:font)
  end
end
```

That link explains how Objective-C messages with *selectors* map to and from RubyMotion, which takes things in a slightly non-Ruby direction in that you can effectively have Ruby methods with identical names "overloaded" as long as they have unique selectors (arguments).

A more RubyMotion way to express your example is:

```
def foo(message, withOffset = 20)
    # Do something
end
```

You were using "`:`" (call value) rather than "`=`" (declare default) syntax.

Comment: So the answer is actually "No", because the author's example was valid ruby 2.0, but does not work on RubyMotion. RubyMotion only has something like it, that help it interop with Obj-C.